# How do we use sinc interpolation to find the domain value if the function value is known in Python?

Tags: python, math, interpolation, data-analysis

I have a discrete data of the change in SNR with frequency in which I need to find the frequency at a certain SNR by using sinc interpolation on the data. So how do we find the frequency, *x,* with a given SNR, *f(x)*? Thank you.

I was able to determine the SNR from a given frequency but not the reverse.

Comment: The inverse could have zero or many solutions no? I suggest you find adjacent peaks and troughs then if your f is between them, you can find the x value of the function with normal techniques like binary chop.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you could have zero or multiple frequencies that correspond to a given SNR value. Using the `sinc_interpolation` function taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/fschwar4/eb462151da065178144d53fe65e8c9fc), you could find approximations to the roots (the frequencies for a given SNR), by evaluating the  sinc-interpolated SNR on a fine grid in frequency and then getting the zero crossing points of the residual (interpolated SNRs - required SNR). E.g.,

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# define sinc interpolation function from https://gist.github.com/fschwar4/eb462151da065178144d53fe65e8c9fc
def sinc_interpolation(x, s, u):
    sinc_ = np.sinc((u - s[:, None]) / (s[1] - s[0]))
    return np.dot(x, sinc_)


def find_freqs(snr, freqs, snrs):
    # get finer grid of frequencies and SNRs
    ffine = np.linspace(freqs[0], freqs[-1], 50 * len(freqs))

    # sinc interpolate SNRs on the finer frequency grid
    snrint = sinc_interpolation(snrs, freqs, ffine)

    # find the (possibly multiple) roots (i.e., when snrint - snr = 0)
    snrres = snrint - snr

    # go through residuals and find frequencies at which it crosses zero
    roots = []
    for i in range(len(snrres) - 1):
        # check for points at which the sign changes
        if snrres[i] * snrres[i + 1] < 0:
            roots.append(ffine[i])

    return roots, ffine, snrint

# example frequencies
f = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)

# example SNRs
snr = np.array([2.2, 5.1, 7.6, 1.1, 3.0, 4.9, 9.2, 2.1, 1.5, 11.3, 12.9])

# SNR at which to find frequencies
snrfind = 4.5

roots, ffine, snrint = find_freqs(snrfind, f, snr)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ffine, snrint)

for root in roots:
    ax.axvline(root, color="k", ls="--")

ax.axhline(snrfind, color="red", ls="--")
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("SNR")

fig.show()
```

[image]